# Getting error while running JavaKafkaWordCount.java

Tags: java, apache-spark, maven-2, apache-kafka

I am submitting JavaKafkaWordCount using following command. I am building the application through Maven

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.mycompany.app.JavaKafkaWordCount --master local[1] /root/my-app/target/my-app-1.0.jar 127.0.0.1:2181 default mytopic 3
```

I got following error and application stopped.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils
at com.mycompany.app.JavaKafkaWordCount.main(JavaKafkaWordCount.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 10 more
```

Below is my pom.xml which I am using to build the jar.

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Below are the plugins.

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>enforce-versions</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <requireMavenVersion>
                    <version>${maven.version}</version>
                  </requireMavenVersion>
                  <requireJavaVersion>
                    <version>${java.version}</version>
                  </requireJavaVersion>
                </rules>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you have the dependency set in your pom file.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

If you do , then make a shaded JAR with all dependencies or pass the external JARs while running your spark-submit script using --jars

Comment: I have already added this dependency. I will try exporting separate jar.

Comment: refer this on making shaded JARs https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to run my code using Uber jar.